# How do I catch errors in a for loop in R?

Tags: r, error-handling, try-catch

I'm running a large for loop in R (unfortunately). There are a lot of random errors that keep popping up. Is there a general code I could put into the for loop that will make it skip to the next iteration in the event of ANY type of error? Thanks. I would greatly appreciate it if you provided me with code I could just copy and paste in, as this is over my head.

Answer (score 2):

```
loop.vals <- 1:6
success <- logical(length(loop.vals))
for(i in loop.vals) 
 if(
   !inherits(
     try({
       if(i %% 2) stop("Random Error")
       cat("Success", i, "\n")
     }, silent=TRUE),  # as per RHertel
     "try-error"
   ) ) success[[i]] <- TRUE
```

Produces:

```
Success 2 
Success 4 
Success 6
```

Then

```
cat("Failures: ", which(!success))
# Failures:  1 3 5
```

---

Old Answer

Sure, you can just `try` the contents of the whole loop.  Here we illustrate with a loop that fails with each odd value

```
for(i in 1:6) try({
  if(i %% 2) stop("Random Error")
  cat("Success", i, "\n")
})
```

Produces:

```
Error in try({ : Random Error
Success 2 
Error in try({ : Random Error
Success 4 
Error in try({ : Random Error
Success 6
```

Comment: You can also choose to refrain from printing error messages and move on with the loop by means of `try( (..whatever may cause trouble...), silent=TRUE)`

Comment: Thanks. And do you know how I could keep track of which iterations were skipped?

Comment: Thanks again. One more question, in some iterations I get the following warning:
`Warning message:
In sqrt(diag(se)) : NaNs produced`
Is there any way to make it skip the iterations that produce this warning (or warnings in general) as well as the errors? THANKS.

Comment: The easiest (but most intrusive way) is to run `options(warn=2)`; this will turn warnings into errors which will then work as you want.  Just remember to turn it off (`options(warn=0)`) once you're done.  Otherwise you can use `tryCatch`, but I won't get into it here.